# Why I must declare type parameter before return type in Java?

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, type-parameter

Without any introduction to generics, I will post my question straight away. Why is this correct:

```
static<T extends Object> void m1(List<T> list){
        //some code
    }
```

And this is not (doesn't compile):

```
static void m2 (List<T extends Object> list){
        //some code
    }
```

Remember that we could use *wildcards* in the same approach, which would compile just fine:

```
static void m2 (List<? extends Object> list){
        //some code
    }
```

To sum up, why can we use *wildcards* declaration in parameters, while using *type parameter* we must declare it before return type?

Comment: Let's say that you wanted to define a type and return an object of that type from the same method. The signature would be `static T <T extends Object> m1(List<T> list)`, but that wouldn't make sense, as `T` would be used **before** it was defined.

Comment: Because the compiler knows what `?` means, but it has no idea what `T` is.  You have to declare `T`, just like you need to declare any variable or method.  First you must declare it, then you can use it.

Comment: If you put `List<T>` as a parameter, there is no indication that `T` is a generic type parameter rather than a concrete type.

Comment: @VGR How does it have no idea what T is? Actually, I just told it that T is child of Object. Yet it complains and forces me to do it in method signature and not in parameters..

Comment: `<T extends Object>` is a declaration.  You are trying to place a declaration in a parameter type.  It would be like writing `List<Integer extends Number>`.

Comment: @VGR I am starting to get your point. On the other size <? extends Object> is not a declaration and compiles fine if I put it inside parameters? That part confuses me, sorry :/

Comment: `<? extends Object>` does not try to define `T` or any other identifier.  It just tells the compiler “This List has a specific type, but I don’t what it is.”

Comment: @Markus Think of `?` like `null`. You don't need to declare it, but `T` you need to. Also notice that you can use anything for `T`. You can write `SomeType` as well. using the `<...>` in the signature is just how you declare such a *generic parameter* for a *generic method*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two main points.

First off, as @akuzminykh said in the comments to the question, the `?` wildcard is basically just a way to tell the compiler "I don't know what this is gonna be, just assume it could be anything that derives from this class/interface, kthxbye". It doesn't declare any parameter that you could make use of within the method, no identifier you can call upon, nothing. However, type parameters do exactly that, and if you declare a new one, it's a different story than just "calling" the wildcard which you don't have to declare.

Secondly, think of how you would declare a type parameter for a generic class. Do you think this would be enough?

```
public class Foo {
    public T extends CharSequence getBar() {...}
}
```

```
public class Foo {
    public <T extends CharSequence> getBar() {...}
}
```

No, none of these two options would work. In order to use a generic type parameter within a class, you have to declare it along with the type itself, not along with the methods/fields that use them. Like this:

```
public class Foo<T extends CharSequence> {
    public T getBar() {...}
}
```

And in order to use a generic type parameter within a method, you have to declare it along with the method itself or the type that contains the method, not along with the method parameters that use them.